# Database Static Roles and Credential Rotation on Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hashicorp-vault

The new 1.2 version of HashiCorp Vault gives you an option for rotating passwords for db users. In earlier versions this was only possible for a root credential users but now there is an option to rotate passwords for as many users as you please. The documentation uses PostgreSQL as an example and I am not sure if this option is available for Microsoft SQL. Does anyone have an idea it's supported or not?

Here is a link to the documentation:
[HashiCorp Docs](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/db-creds-rotation)

Comment: The reference documentation suggests that Vault can operate with SQL Server - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/databases/mssql.html

Comment: Sure, vault can and I am using that with SQL Server utilizing the root rotation for one. But unsure if the new features in 1.2 are available for SQL Server.